# Websockets - wrapper framework or as is?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websocket

We are researching the new `websockets` in regard to our new generation project. (java web application)
My question is - are there any frameworks that helps you working with `websockets` (client side)? or does the websocket usage is pretty straight forward with `onMessage.getStringFromServer()`,  `sendStringToServer()` ??

thanks

Comment: is "client side" in your mind only a web browser with javascript?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html

Answer (score 0):

I used vert.x to deal with websocket (in the context of tests).
For example, listening to events can be done as it :

```
  Vertx vertx = VertxFactory.newVertx()
  HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient().setHost("YOUR_HOST").setPort(PORT).connectWebsocket("PATH_TO_YOUR_WEBSOCKET_RESOURCE", handler)
```

the handler has to implements Handler interface. For example, I used this to add amm eve,ts tp a list

```
class RealTimeEventHandler implements Handler<WebSocket> {
  EventsCollector collector

  public RealTimeEventHandler(EventsCollector collector) {
    this.collector = collector;
  }

  @Override
  void handle(WebSocket e) {
    e.dataHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
      @Override
      void handle(Buffer b) {
        println b.toString()
        collector.addEvent(new JsonSlurper().parseText(b.toString()))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

An other possibility may be from atmosphere framework, it's author developped a framewor : wasync which handle such request but I have no feedback on its use.

Hope it helps